# Why do chat messages exist under user name after deleting account?

Tags: support, chat, user-accounts

I deleted all but some SE accounts for various reasons, and I deleted my Puzzling SE account, too. Before deleting my account, I posted a lot of chat messages in Puzzling SE's chat like [The Sphinx Lair](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) or [A Letter From the past](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46319/a-letter-from-the-past). But they are still showing, with my name in the chat, even after deletion!

Screenshots (If you're lazy to click one the links) [I am Arbitrary Kangaroo]:

[image]

(and hey, that time my total rep was not 841, either)

I would like to get **all** of them deleted.

Comment: just to point out something. those links look like they take you into the chat room and the most recent messages posted, after a day or a month your messages will no longer appear and someone will have to hunt them down. i would suggest using the permalink which will redirect the user to the message in the transcript

Comment: @Memor-X:  In the Letter from the past, my messages are visible with very minute scrolling

Comment: true but if you use something like [this link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32868696#32868696) or even the [day's trsnscript link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46319/2016/10/12) there's no need to scroll at all even when more posts are made later on

Comment: You have a single chat account for all Stack Exchange sites minus SO and Meta. The system does not selectively delete things when you delete a profile from a specific site.

Comment: as for your actual problem. i'm probably wrong but if you delete the account you have set as the parent user i would suspect it changes to another account. even if you are able to disassociate every account with chat i would assume the posts remain, just that the link wont work and it'll default to the user user######## username

Comment: @Memor-X No, parent user has no effect in this case.

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo Link me to one of those posts. I'll anonymize them for you. Deleting isn't going to happen since that'd break a lot of the conversations you were a part of.

Comment: @AdamLear i see. i thought it did because if you had different usernames between accounts the parent user uses the information of that account including if the account is a mod account (and thus makes the text blue)

Comment: @Memor-X I can see how you'd get there... but it doesn't really translate to profile deletions, no.

Comment: @animuson So how I can delete my parent chat account / parent SE account. ?

Comment: @AdamLear Anonymizing a single post ain't going to  work - but if you can, then anonymize all my posts on  the  above two chat and REJBAS  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46155/REJBAS     if  doing so it's not tedious.

Comment: Offtopic: I am sad to see you go.

Answer (score 10):

As animuson mentioned in the comments, your chat.stackexchange account is shared between all Stack Exchange sites except Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange.

I anonymized the existing messages linked to your chat profile (there's unfortunately no way to do that for just specific chat rooms - it's all or nothing). Going forward, whatever you post will be associated with your current profiles.

Please let me know if there's anything else you need in relation to this issue.

Comment: Excellent -  that's what I wanted (making all previous chat anonymous)

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo Great. Happy to help. :)

Comment: Is there any way to do this manually (i.e without asking the mods for help) ?

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo No, you need to get an employee involved to do this.

Comment: Okay. Just two other (off topic) questions: 1. Is the deletion requests handled manually ? 2. When you delete all other SE accounts, does the chat SE account get deleted automatically ?

Comment: 1. It's mostly self-serve, unless the account has a lot of votes or reputation. In that case an employee gets involved. 2. Yes.

Comment: I am verry sorry to request again - but can you please do it again for just once more ? (https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/249754) Thanks in advance (I have no account on any SE except meta.se)

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo Sure, done.

Comment: Hey, can you please anonymized the existing messages linked to my chat profile? I want my chat messages and profile to be deleted permanently.